# Kali Linux on Raspberry Pi zero

Tags: sd-card

Using Microsoft Windows, how do I get this file on an SD card to use on a Raspberry Pi Zero?

```
kali-2.1.2-rpi.img.xz
```

Comment: My apologies for the original down vote. I hadn't noticed the `xz` extension on the end and assumed this was a standard install. I have removed the down vote and changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Dealing with Compression**

The `xz` extension on the end of the file means that the `img` file is compressed using LZMA or LZMA2 compression. On Windows, the best way to unzip the file is using an open source tool called [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Use the graphical interface to extract the `img` file, then install the `img` file normally.

**Installing the IMG file**

The official Raspberry Pi site has [a tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md) on how to write an image to the sd card when running Windows.

From their website:

1. Insert the SD card into your SD card reader and check which drive letter was assigned. You can easily see the drive letter, such as G:, by looking in the left column of Windows Explorer. You can use the SD card slot if you have one, or a cheap SD adapter in a USB port.
2. Download the Win32DiskImager utility from the Sourceforge Project page as a zip file; you can run this from a USB drive.
3. Extract the executable from the zip file and run the Win32DiskImager utility; you may need to run this as administrator. Right-click on the file, and select Run as administrator.
   4.Select the image file you extracted earlier.
4. Select the drive letter of the SD card in the device box. Be careful to select the correct drive; if you get the wrong one you can destroy the data on your computer's hard disk! If you are using an SD card slot in your computer and can't see the drive in the Win32DiskImager window, try using an external SD adapter.
5. Click Write and wait for the write to complete.
6. Exit the imager and eject the SD card.

Comment: Hi, Appreciate the answer. I am still having an issue, I cannot seem to get anything to work on  Win32DiskImager. Any advice would be appreciated. Running Windows 10 on an Acer ES1-512-C323 laptop. thanks    Donnie

Comment: @Pilot: what error did you get?